# Need help understanding an exception in Tomcat servlet

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets, servlet-filters

I have the following exception:

```
Servlet.service() for servlet indexpage threw exception java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.apache.catalina.servlets.DefaultServlet.serveResource(DefaultServlet.java:675)
at org.apache.catalina.servlets.DefaultServlet.doHead(DefaultServlet.java:351)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:634)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at planplatform.cors.CorsFilter.doFilter(CorsFilter.java:61)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:298)
at org.apache.jk.server.JkCoyoteHandler.invoke(JkCoyoteHandler.java:190)
at org.apache.jk.common.HandlerRequest.invoke(HandlerRequest.java:291)
at org.apache.jk.common.ChannelSocket.invoke(ChannelSocket.java:769)
at org.apache.jk.common.ChannelSocket.processConnection(ChannelSocket.java:698)
at org.apache.jk.common.ChannelSocket$SocketConnection.runIt(ChannelSocket.java:891)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPool$ControlRunnable.run(ThreadPool.java:690)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

The only code in this exception that is mine is the CorsFilter:

```
HttpServletRequest req = (HttpServletRequest) servletRequest;
    HttpServletResponse resp = (HttpServletResponse) servletResponse;

    String origin = req.getHeader("Origin");

    boolean shouldAllowCorsOnOrigin = allowCorsOnOrigin(origin);

    if (shouldAllowCorsOnOrigin) 
    {
        resp.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", origin);
        resp.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");

        resp.setHeader("Allow", "GET, HEAD, POST, PUT, DELETE, TRACE, OPTIONS");

        String headers = req.getHeader("Access-Control-Request-Headers");
        String method = req.getHeader("Access-Control-Request-Method");
        resp.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", method);
        resp.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", headers);

        if ("options".equalsIgnoreCase(req.getMethod())) 
        {
            resp.setContentType("text/plain");

            resp.getWriter().flush();
            return;
        }
    }

    // Fix ios6 caching post requests
    if ("post".equalsIgnoreCase(req.getMethod())) {
        resp.addHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
    }

    if (filterChain != null) {
        filterChain.doFilter(req, resp);
    }
```

shouldAllowCorsOnOrigin is false, so the code does not enter to the large if.

Any ideas why the exception happens?

Comment: What is line 61 of the CorstFilter?

Comment: filterChain.doFilter(req, resp);

Comment: The exception does not happen locally but only on production servers and i can't reproduce it in debug mode.

Comment: The `CorsFilter` is in the stack trace since the request passes throught the filter chain, but it does not origin there. What does your `indexpage` servlet look like?

Comment: The code does not get to the indexpage servlet.

Comment: Is it a JSP then? The stack trace certainly says that it's `indexpage` that is causing the exception. Also, it says it's within `doHead`. What kind of request is causing the error?

Answer (score 1):

I would get the version number of Tomcat and look up the source code for DefaultServlet for that version.  I looked up 6.0.26, but the line number in the stack trace doesn't coincide with a line that can throw this error.

The method in DefaultServlet that is throwing the error depends on resources obtained from either its own context or a JNDI lookup.  Look further back in your logs for an exception with "No resources" as its message.  There are two constants the DefaultServlet.init() method uses to look up resources -- does the server environment have resources for one of them?

Comment: yeah, thats what i tried either - the line number does not make any sense

Comment: well, if you want help, you're going to have to give more information.  What version is the server using, and how do you know, so that someone else can look at it?

Comment: Yep, the exact version of tomcat is required to diagnose this one

Answer (score 0):

You should look at indexpage servlet, probably there is a problem, because in your stacktrace, you have null pointer during `Servlet.service()` and this method is called by the servlet container to allow the servlet to respond to a request. Before of that `init` method is executed (at indexpage). Could you show us indexpage servlet?

Comment: If the problem was in the indexpage servlet, would not i see it in the stack? It seems that the exception happens before calling to the servlet itself, no? The servlet is quite complex and unfortunately i can't share its code